# Cómo validar en Java un hash generado en PHP con `password_hash` y PASSWORD_BCRYPT

Tags: php, java

Tengo una pagina web en donde los usuarios se tienen que registrar, en la base de datos almaceno la contraseña de esta forma utilizando php

```
$password = $_POST['contraseña'];
$passHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); //password encrypt
```

Todo funciona bien, pero la cuestión esta en que el login lo estoy desarrollando en java, así que necesito validar la contraseña que ingrese el usuario en el programa java, investigué un poco y encontré sobre la librería [Bcrypt](https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt), intenté esto para comparar el hash que recupero de la base de datos con el hash que genera esta librería a la contraseña que ingrese el usuario (las mismas contraseñas):

```
String hash = rs.getString("password"); //password BD
String hashPassword = BCrypt.hashpw(password); //input
                
System.out.println(hash);
System.out.println(hashPassword);
```

Los resultados son estos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Presiento que estoy omitiendo algo, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Pues deberías ver exactamente con qué parámetros crea la contraseña la librería de PHP y usar los mismos parámetros en tu librería de Java, ya que al utilizarlo sin parametrizar estás dependiendo de que ambos desarrolladores hayan decidido usar los mismos valores por defecto... y no suele ser así :)

Comment: Supuse que el algoritmo de encriptación Bcrypt sería igual en ambos, si investigué como funciona la librería de PHP pero nada relevante que me permita obtener el mismo hash con java

Comment: Esto es lo que buscas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480375/whats-the-java-equivalent-for-phps-password-hash-and-password-verify

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP, Hola, precisamente ese código es el que estoy intentando, de ahí descubrí la librería

Comment: La librería BCrypt de java pide como parametro la cantidad de saltos, ya sea 10 o 12, pero ninguno me genera el mismo hash que la que genera php... no se como funcionará ese password_hash de php

Comment: Creo que tienes que usar la réplica para password_verify()

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP ese metodo de checkpw me devuelve false, por lo mismo de que los dos hash son diferentes, si encripto la contraseña desde java pues si devuelve true, pero si trato de validar el hash que me genera php devuelve false

Comment: ¿Y si pasas el password directamente de Java a PHP y que la comparación la haga PHP?

Comment: @MauricioContreras pensé en eso pero no conozco el método, como podría hacerle?

Comment: Puede que funcione si en vez de pasar `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` a `password_hash` le pasas `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`. Pero eso te obligaría a cambiar las contraseñas que ya tienes registradas. Cuando usas `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` el algoritmo usado es CRYPT_BLOWFISH. Quizá debas buscar el equivalente a la función `crypt`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292160/equivalent-of-phps-crypt-function-in-java

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP lo intenté también, pero nada... :(

Comment: Una cosa que tienes que tener clara es que validar el hash comparándolo con una encriptación de la contraseña no te va a funcionar, ni siquiera haciéndolo con PHP, porque `password_hash` pone una salt aleatoria cada vez que encripta, por lo que el resultado sobre una misma contraseña nunca es el mismo. Hay que usar `password_verify` para validar los hashes. Así que necesitas el equivalente a `password_verify`  en Java.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP el equivalente de `password verify` en java es esto: `boolean s = BCrypt.checkpw("password", hash);` pero al pasarle el hash pues me devuelve false al pasarle el hash que genera php

Comment: Prueba con un hash generado así: `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`, a ver si vamos descubriendo algo.

Comment: Una cosa: ¿has probado a verificar un hash desde PHP? Porque creo que también te va a fallar. Estoy pensando que tus hashes no están completos. Un hash generado con `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` debería medir 60 caracteres, pero el que sale en tu ejemplo tiene menos. Es posible que se estén cortando por alguna razón, por ejemplo si el campo de la base de datos tiene menos capacidad.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Amigo tenías toda la razón, ya acabo de hacer lo que dijiste y efectivamente era eso, desde mi ignorancia pensé que los hash debían ser iguales y pues estaba aplicando mal mi logica, con el puro metodo de checkpw pasandole el password y el hash de la BD ya lo valida correctamente

Comment: Además, también tenías razón sobre el campo de mi base de datos, tenía capacidad de 50 caracteres, le puse 100 y ahora si ya no lo corta

Comment: Por favor, agrega una respuesta formal a la pregunta para poder aceptarla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero, una cosa importante a tener en cuenta: **no puedes validar un hash volviendo a encriptar la contraseña y comparando**, porque esta forma de encriptación pone una *salt* aleatoria cada vez, de forma que nunca genera dos hash iguales para la misma contraseña. Eso servía cuando simplemente se encriptaba por ejemplo con `md5`, pero en este caso hay que usar un validador de hash, en PHP sería la función `password_verify`. Así que necesitas el equivalente en Java a `password_verify`.

Sin embargo, lo usas y no te funciona. Entonces, revisando tu ejemplo, veo algo raro. Los hashes generados en PHP con `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` miden 60 caracteres, sin embargo el de tu ejemplo es más corto. Ese hash ni siquiera lo vas a poder validar desde PHP, porque está cortado.

Es seguro que en tu aplicación se **están cortando los hashes** por alguna razón. Una muy probable es que el campo de la base de datos en el que guardas los hashes (las contraseñas encriptadas) tiene una capacidad menor de 60 caracteres.

Revisa eso y creo que te deberá funcionar la validación desde Java con `BCrypt.checkpw()`.

```
boolean s = BCrypt.checkpw("password", hash);
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu respuesta me ayudó mucho